# How can you configure Chrome to show Extension icons in multiple rows instead of one?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I have many Extensions (>20) installed in Chrome that I use frequently.

All show up next to the address bar, making the address bar quite tiny on most screens.

[image: address bar screengrab]

Is there a way to either have the icons show up in multiple rows (like how you can expand the Taskbar on Windows to have more than one row), or put them in a drop-down, or some other way to make sure they're readily-accessibly, but don't take up most of what would otherwise be your address bar's screen real estate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is a way to make them show up in multiple rows and at the same time put them in a drop-down menu.

- Right click on an extension icon.
- Select **Hide in Chrome Menu**

The extension will be put in the three dotted settings-button on the far right of your toolbar. Do this with as many extensions you want. They will be displayed as icons in rows like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpjnC.png)